# Are $\Bbb C^4 $and polynomials of degree at most five isomorphic vector spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-space-isomorphism

I'm curious that: Are $\Bbb C^4$ and polynomials of degree at most five isomorphic vector spaces? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What are the dimensions of each?

Comment: what do you mean by dimensions

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_(vector_space)

Comment: one of them C^4 and the other most fifth degree polynomials?

Comment: $C^4$ is a vector space. The set of polynomials of degree $\le 5$ also is a vector space. You want to know if they are isomorphic. Isomorphic vector spaces must have the same dimension, so maybe we should check that the dimensions of the two vector spaces match.

Comment: Isn’t the exponential function $C^4$?

Comment: @Lubin he is talking about the set of all functions with 4 continuous derivatives

Comment: @gt6989b I wouldn't assume so without further context - it's as likely that OP is asking about $\mathbb{C}^4$, i.e., the space of all four-component vectors over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Also, 'as vbector spaces over what'?  Pedantically, the answer may be different over different base fields - for instance, they can be isomorphic as vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$...

Comment: This question asked to us and there was no any different extra data. so i couldnt do it:/

Comment: So this was homework? If you know the dimension of the space of polynomials of degree less than $6$ and find one $C^4$ function not in that space, that should do it for you.

Comment: @dmbizlak Is the `C` written like $C$, or like $\Bbb C$?

Comment: @pjs36 sorry i am new in this site

Comment: I feel it should be obvious the question is about $\Bbb C^4$ rather than $C^4$ functions (as in @Lubin's comments), since comparing coordinate vector spaces to spaces of polynomials is a standard textbook intro linear algebra exercise but dealing with differentiability classes is the stuff of a different textbook. (Also: even if we were talking about $C^4$, we'd technically still have to note the polynomials are a subspace of $C^4$, and then after demonstrating it's a proper subspace we must note the difference in infinitude of dimension. Some spaces are isomorphic to proper subspaces!)

Comment: @gt6989b Yes, that's what Lubin was actually implying, although I think that interpretation is clearly wrong.

Comment: Yes, my appollogies: I seem to have been fixated on the most improbable interpretation of OP’s question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are taking $\Bbb C^4$ as a vector over $\Bbb C$ right ?
Then both your vector spaces will have different dimensions hence not isomorphic.

Edit: It doesn't matter you are considering  $\Bbb C^4$ as a vector over $\Bbb C$  or $\Bbb R$, in any case it will have different dimension to polynomials of degree at most 5.